# Can "oblivion" also be considered a place?

Tags: word-usage

> **oblivion** 
>  əˈblɪvɪən/noun1.
>   the state of being unaware or unconscious of what is happening around one.
>   "they drank themselves
>   into oblivion"

So according to the dictionary, it's a state. But can one treat it as a place?

Example:

> Tom's father died; he's now in oblivion, resting blissfully in peace.

In this sentence, I'm treating *oblivion* more like a place than a state of mind. Is this weird? If so, what's a more appropiate word?

Comment: You can treat it like a place one is *sent to*, but not one where people reside or exist. That's kind of the point. It's conceptually similar to `/dev/null` : you can send anything you want there, but no matter what or how much you send, when you go look, there's nothing there. It's empty. Void.

Comment: . . . from which it would seem to follow that predicating rest or bliss or even being would be nonsensical. (Also, the usual and preferable verb for the complement *to oblivion* is *consign.)*

Comment: If *you* think it's weird, it's weird. If you don't, the usage is fine. It's just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not only weird -- it just doesn't work.  As Dan says in his comment, nobody can be resting peacefully in oblivion.  Oblivion is devoid of anything.  A more appropriate "place" word would be "the hereafter" or "a better place."  Or get rid of the resting blissfully part.

Comment: What if I replace "blissfully" for "eternally" or "forever"?

Comment: You'd have to nix "resting" along with it.  "He's now in oblivion, eternally at peace" would work.  Or replace "oblivion" with "eternity" in your original sentence.

Answer (score 1):

To the ears of an everyday English-speaker, “*Tom's father died; he's now in oblivion, resting blissfully in peace*,” would likely be misunderstood, at best, as acerbic irony, and at worst as disrespect for the dead. Moreover, your example usage would not be understood as a “place” but rather as an “**existential state**,” i.e., **the state of non-being**. That said, *oblivion*, in the sense of unconsciousness or unawareness does connote with a state of ignorance, which is often idiomatically characterized as "*bliss*,” e.g., “*ignorance is bliss*.”

I would not recommend this usage of *oblivion*, for the reasons stated above. As an alternative you might say, “*Tom’s father has died. His suffering has now ended, may he rest in peace*.”

> [**oblivion**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivion) *noun*:
>
> **1**. the state of something that is not remembered, used, or thought about any more.
>
> **2**. the state of being unconscious or unaware: the state of not knowing what is going on around you,
>
> **3**. the state of being destroyed.

(Merriam-Webster *online*)

**Etymology**

> [**oblivion**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=oblivion&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.) late 14c., "state or fact of forgetting," from Old French oblivion (13c.) and directly from Latin *oblivionem* (nominative *oblivio*) "forgetfulness; a being forgotten," from *oblivisci* (past participle *oblitus*) "forget," originally "even out, smooth over, efface," from *ob* "over" (see ob-) + root of *levis* "smooth," from PIE lei-w-, from root *(s)lei- "slime, slimy, sticky" (see slime (n.)). Meaning "state of being forgotten" is early 15c. (etymonline)
>
> [**oblivious**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=oblivious&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.) mid-15c., from Latin *obliviosus* "forgetful, that easily forgets; producing forgetfulness," from *oblivion* (see oblivion). Meaning "unaware, unconscious (of something)" is from 1862, formerly regarded as erroneous, this is now the general meaning and the word has lost its original sense of "no longer aware or mindful." Properly should be used with to, not of. Related: Obliviously; obliviousness.

(etymonline)